# Rewriting infinity as a limit to infinity (in terms of Fourier series)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Put informally: When writing down the complex Fourier series of a function, is it proper to write
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \tag*{(1)}$$
or
$$\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{n=-k}^k? \tag*{(2)}$$

From what I've seen, I can tell that the representation $(1)$ has been used more often. However, I encountered a case when $(1)$ is not valid:
$$\pi\cot \pi z=\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{n=-k}^k \dfrac{1}{z+n},$$
but
$$\pi\cot\pi z\ne\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{z+n},$$
as it diverges.

Comment: @PeterForeman : The symmetric partial sums here are exactly the partial sums of the series in the first link, as $$\frac1{z-n}+\frac1{z+n}=\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}.$$ The second is only an artful symmetrization of the form in the first link. Where do you see the error occurring?

Comment: My mistake, I was only considering the separate sums from $n\gt0$ and $n\lt0$ then adding them.

Comment: @PeterForeman : That's why only the "principal value" formulation works here, not the unrestricted summation over $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbolic form $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{z+n}$$ means
$$
\lim_{a,b\to\infty}\sum_{n=-a}^b \dfrac{1}{z+n},
$$
that is, the limit should not depend on the path to infinity that the pair $(a,b)$ takes in the grid $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. In the given example, this is not the case as the one-sided series are harmonic sums that diverge on their own. Only the occurrence of the opposite terms balances the symmetric sums to get convergence. As example of an unbalanced path to infinity take $(a_k,b_k)=(k,2^k)$.

Comment: So, when someone writes down the general Fourier series as $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots$, is it implicitly assumed that the $\lim$ should be used instead if necessary?

Comment: You can always say that $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty=\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}+\sum_0^\infty$, where the separate convergence of both one-sided series is required. As always, absolute summability implies that the series converges in all forms.